# appending not working and not showing error too

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call function.to open the popup to the screen.but it not show the pop up and not showing error too.function is calling properly tried print detail using console.log. Data is coming properly.i think some issue while appending the popup division.please help me out.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function viewCamp(id) {
    $('#customModal').remove();
    listable = "<h1 style='text-align: center;'>Camp Details<h1>";
    $.get("camp-details-ajax.php?e2c=" + id, function(data) {
      obj = $.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(obj);
      listable += "<table style='text-align:left'>";
      listable += "<tr><th>Organization name</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_NAME + "</td></tr>";
      listable += "<tr><th>Name of contact person</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_PRINCIPAL_NAME + "</td></tr>";
      listable += "<tr><th>Mobile Number</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_CONTACT_NUM + "</td></tr>";
      if (obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_LANDLINE != '' && obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_LANDLINE != null) {
        listable += "<tr><th>Landline Number</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_STD_CODE + "-" + obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_LANDLINE + "</td></tr>";
      }
      listable += "<tr><th>Email</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_EMAIL + "</td></tr>";
      listable += "<tr><th>Address1</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_ADD1 + "</td></tr>";
      listable += "<tr><th>Address2</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_ADD2 + "</td></tr>";
      if (obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_ADD3 != '' && obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_ADD3 != null) {
        listable += "<tr><th>Address3</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_ADD3 + "</td></tr>";
      }
      listable += "<tr><th>City </th><td>" + obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_CITY + "</td></tr>";
      listable += "<tr><th>State</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_STATE + "</td></tr>";
      listable += "<tr><th>Pincode</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_SCHOOL_PIN + "</td></tr>";
      listable += "<tr><th>Doctor Name</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_TEMP_DENT_NAME + "</td></tr>";
      listable += "<tr><th>Doctor Email</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_TEMP_DENT_EMAIL + "</td></tr>";
      listable += "<tr><th>Doctor Mobile</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_TEMP_DENT_MOBILE + "</td></tr>";
      listable += "<tr><th>Strength of Whole School/Organization</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_NO_OF_STUDENT + "</td></tr>";
      listable += "<tr><th>Number of Students/Children attending</th><td>" + obj.CAMP_NO_OF_STU_ATTEND + "</td></tr>";
      listable += "</table>";
      $('body').append('  <div class="modal fade" id="customModal" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"> <div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-body"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><img src="images/close.png" class="img-responsive" width="100%"  ></button><p>' + listable + '</p></div></div></div></div>');
    });
  }
  $('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
    $('#customModal').remove();
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry it's kind of hard to tell from your comment, but does `console.log(obj);` print the object correctly?

Comment: May be some special characters (i.e ",", "'" ,apostrophe, / ) in your received data like Address1, Address2, Name etc.. Please check 
Javacript will cause for special character and it will break syntax. Easy to debug remove or comment some code and verify. Thank you
If it's full code, will help you

Comment: yes obj print correctly

Comment: add this code after appending to body tag `$('#customModal').modal('show')` and also check in inspect element whether customModal is added in body somewhere!

Comment: i am trying to appending from js only not from body

Comment: I agree with @Dhiren. It should be work. try to added `$('#customModal').modal('show');` after the line `$('body').append......`. If you need sample, I can provide.

Comment: Make a working example that shows your situation, at jsfiddle for example.

Comment: thnx  @Jitendra its working now...wrote $('#customModal').modal('show'); after$('body').append......